# Datediff me da un valor booleano al comparar dos fechas

Tags: php, revisión-de-código, date, session, sesiones

Tengo un login.php en el que valido un usuario, y si es el correcto, abro la sesión. El código es el siguiente:

```
    if (password_verify($pass,$resultado)) {
                        session_start();
                        $_SESSION['nick'] = $nickjugador;
                        $_SESSION['instante'] = time();
                        echo "Enhorabuena ".$_SESSION['nick'].", te has logueado, puedes acceder a <a href='cpanel.php'>Panel de control</a>";
                    }
                    else {
                        die(

"El nombre o la contraseña no coinciden");
                }
```

En cpanel php quiero calcular la diferencia entre el tiempo en el que se inició la sesión y si la diferencia es de 3 horas y media, o de 4 horas, que se cierre la sesión. Sin embargo cuando hago un vardump de `datediff()$diferencia = date_diff($_SESSION['instante'], $fechanueva);` me devuelve un valor booleano.

Comment: Ese booleano que comentas ¿es un FALSE? Ésto seria así en caso de error, por ejemplo si $_SESSION['instante'] no existe. ¿Lo has comprobado antes de usar la función?

Comment: Me da un booleano false, sí.

Comment: Yo lo primero que haría, a parte de mirar la documentación de PHP, es un debug de lo que le meto a la función que me esta fallando.

Comment: No tiene mucho sentido pasarle un debugger, porque la función en sí no falla, sino que da un valor booleano, no obstante, lo he hecho y no marca error.

Comment: De https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_diff.asp que ésta más claro: **Return Value: Returns a DateInterval object on success that represents the difference between the two dates. FALSE on failure**
Tu obtienes un FALSE, valora porque.

Comment: Pero el debugger no marca nada, no entiendo para qué lo necesito. Y precisamente eso es lo que estoy preguntando aqui

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61851/discussion-between-orici-and-ras212).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si asignas el "instante" con `time()` estás asignando un integer, no una fecha. Puedes probar con algo como esto:

```
$fechanueva1 = date("2017-07-08 08:20:30");
$fechanueva2 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

if( is_string( $fechanueva1)) $fechanueva1 = date_create( $fechanueva1);
if( is_string( $fechanueva2)) $fechanueva2 = date_create( $fechanueva2);

$diferencia = date_diff($fechanueva1, $fechanueva2);
var_dump($diferencia);
```

El resultado será un objeto de la clase [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/es/class.dateinterval.php):

```
object(DateInterval)[3]
  public 'y' => int 0
  public 'm' => int 0
  public 'd' => int 1
  public 'h' => int 0
  public 'i' => int 0
  public 's' => int 33
  public 'weekday' => int 0
  public 'weekday_behavior' => int 0
  public 'first_last_day_of' => int 0
  public 'invert' => int 0
  public 'days' => int 1
  public 'special_type' => int 0
  public 'special_amount' => int 0
  public 'have_weekday_relative' => int 0
  public 'have_special_relative' => int 0
```

Comment: Pero la fecha no puedo definirla a mano yo, debe hacerse cuando se haga el login.

Comment: Puedes hacerla con `date` en vez de con `time`. Te asignará un String que luego puedes convertir a formato fecha en vez de un integer. `date_diff` devuelve la diferencia entre dos objetos DateTime, no puede comparar integers.

Comment: Pero la diferencia sí es un  integer no? Aunque los parámetros que le paso yo no lo sean

Comment: El resultado es un `array`. ¿Has probado el código que te he adjuntado? ¿Has leido el manual?. Creo que deberías empezar por leerlo: [date_diff](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: Tambié puedes convertir el integer que te devuelve `time()`, pero a date_diff tienes que darle 2 fechas:

`date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $_SESSION['instante']);`

Comment: Sí, he probado con ```date("Y-m-d H:i:s")``` y tampoco funciona

Comment: Vale, pero ¿que es lo que no funciona?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61852/discussion-between-ras212-and-javi-ps).

Comment: No va, quiero obtener los segundos de ese array```<?php
session_start();
echo "Bienvenido ".$_SESSION['nick']." , has iniciado sesión en la fecha ".$_SESSION['instante']."</br>";
$fechanueva = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo "</br>";
if (is_string($fechanueva) && is_string($_SESSION['instante'])) {
    $fecha1 = date_create($_SESSION['instante']);
    $fecha2 = date_create($fechanueva);
    //Calculamos la diferencia
    $diferencia = date_diff($fecha1,$fecha2);
  
    var_dump($difrencia->s);
}
else {
    die("Error de sesión");
}
?>```

Comment: El código que pones funciona correctamente, después de arreglar el error tipográfico  `var_dump($difrencia->s);` El problema que veo es que si quieres saber la diferencia, como dices en tu enunciado, en horas no te vale con sacar sólo los segundos, sino que tendrás que calcular días + horas + minutos + segundos.

Answer (score 1):

¿Editaste tu código? creo que he visto antes que en sesión metes el resultado de date(), que te devuelve un string, puedes probar lo siguiente:

```
if ( isset( $_SESSION[ 'instante' ])) {

    $instante = date_create( $_SESSION[ 'instante' ]); //si guardo resultado de date()
    $fechanueva = date_create( date( "Y-m-d H:i:s" ));

    $diferencia = date_diff( 
        $instante, 
        $fechanueva 
    );


    echo "<pre>"; var_dump( $diferencia ); //Debug ressults

} else {

    //Tratar error
}
```